# Problem with Linq query .net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

[image]

```
public ActionResult Performances(string id)
    {
        var query =
    from f in _db.Production
    join g in _db.Run on f.show equals g.Production.show
    join l in _db.Performance on g.startDate equals l.runStartDate
    where f.show == id
    select new ShowPerformance
    {
        Venuename = g.venue,
        Showname = f.show,
        RunStart = g.startDate,
        RunEnd = g.endDate,
        PerformanceDate = l.performanceDate,
        PerformanceTime = l.performanceTime
    };


    return View(query.ToList());


    }
```

The query can not distuingish between a performance in ShowA run1 and Show A run2 it just duplicates all performances ShowA run1 and Show A run2

Comment: could you provide an exerpt of the data in the database?

Comment: First, may I suggest changing the variable names to something that makes it easier to follow (prod, run and perf instead of f,g and l).  Also, I am curious about the join line - what is Production.show?

Comment: @HitLikeAHammer @Femaref Thanks for answering. The answer below does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be how you join Performance to Run/Production

```
var query =
        from f in _db.Production
        join g in _db.Run on new {f.show, f.year} equals new {g.show, g.year}
        join l in _db.Performance on new {g.venue, g.startDate} equals new {l.venue, l.runStartDate}
        where f.show == id 
        select new ShowPerformance
        {
            Venuename = g.venue,
            Showname = f.show,
            RunStart = g.startDate,
            RunEnd = g.endDate,
            PerformanceDate = l.performanceDate,
            PerformanceTime = l.performanceTime
        };
```

without something like the `on g.runId equals l.runId` then you will get all the performances for all the productions/runs.

Comment: @Stuart Thanks the query works great, gets only performances for the particular show.

Comment: @Stuart I have since added another run of the same production and the query does not distinguish between runs and pulls all performances for both runs. I have updated the question with a picture of my er diagram if that can offer some help.

Comment: how are the performance and run joined together? It looks like you need to do quite a complicated CROSS JOIN with something like `where g.venue == l.venue && g.startDate <= l.performanceDate && g.endDate >= l.performanceDate` - sit back and think about this - you know this database - we don't!

Comment: I'm also worried about "year" being a field in the database - surely that's part of date?

Comment: They are joined through the Venue and RunStartdate as foreign keys

Comment: in that case put both of those fields into the join expression - see above

Comment: .... but if there's any way that you can change that SQL database schema to make it easier to follow (e.g. using simple ID fields for each table) then please do!

Comment: @Stuart thanks for all your help, I have got it working correctly. Your example was fine all along, I just wasn't passing the data through to the view. I was only passing the Show name not the Showname plus Perfromance/Run start dates.